# No call to my didSelectRowAtIndexPath function

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm trying to create an app that displays some data on labels on the top of a screen, and then the lower half or so is a table which will allow selection of an item in the table to pop up another segue for editing a value. I'm struggling though to get the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to be called when an item on the list is selected by the user. I've put the code for the View controller below.

I've searched quite a bit and haven't found anything so far that explains the issue I'm seeing.

I think I've connected everything up correctly as far as delegates and datasource, and I'm not using any gesture captures so it's not those. Does anyone have any ideas?

I've attached screen grabs of the view controller connections and attributes inspector settings as well.

[Connections screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGd4t.jpg)

[Attributes screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/136hH.jpg)

```
import UIKit

class TemperatureViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var CurrentTemp: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var HeaterStatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChillerStatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TempTableView: UITableView!

    var settings = [TemperatureSettings] ()

    var HeaterTemp:Float = 0.0
    var ChillerTemp:Float = 0.0
    var ThresholdTemp:Float = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.loadTempSettings()
        TempTableView.delegate = self
        TempTableView.dataSource = self
        TempTableView.allowsSelection   = true
        TempTableView.editing = false
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.loadTempSettings()  

    }

    func loadTempSettings() {


        let TempSetting1 = TemperatureSettings(name: "Heater On at", CurrentSetting: HeaterTemp)!

        let TempSetting2 = TemperatureSettings(name: "Chiller On at", CurrentSetting: ChillerTemp)!

        let TempSetting3 = TemperatureSettings(name: "Threshold", CurrentSetting: ThresholdTemp)!

        settings = [TempSetting1, TempSetting2, TempSetting3]

        TempTableView.reloadData()

        //refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return settings.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Stop spoof separators after the table entries for blank entries
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)

        // Turn off the separator for each cell.
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

        let cellIdentifier = "TemperatureSettingsTableViewCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TemperatureSettingsTableViewCell

        let setting = settings[indexPath.row]

        cell.SettingNameLabel.text = setting.name
        cell.SettingCurrentLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f C", setting.CurrentSetting)
        cell.SettingCurrentLabel.textAlignment = .Left

        // Configure the cell...

        //useTimer = true

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("Setting Row \(indexPath.row) clicked")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Settings", sender: self)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Just to add, the data is being populated in the table so that part is working, just user interaction that isn't.

Comment: Is your tableView drawing properly and just the row not being selected? have you checked your tableView selectionMode?

Comment: Is your UITableViewDelegate properly set in your UITableView and the selection mode to Single Selection?

Comment: Yes it's displaying properly, just not calling the function when a row is selected by the user. The two screen grabs I uploaded ( links above the code ) show the delegate setup and the selection modes, I think they're correct and set for single selection.

Comment: How do you present this view controller?

Comment: How do you mean by present? the view controller is launched from another UITableViewController with a manual segue if that's helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("works");
}
```

Add override before `func` maybe?

Comment: Sadly not as Xcode tells me that "Method dos not override any method from it's superclass" Presumably as it's a ViewController class I'm using as the base.

Comment: I'm using Version 7.0 beta 4 I'm going to download 7.2 and see what happens but I'm not sure it is a bug in Xcode

Comment: Then try starting a new project or restart Xcode? No sure why you're getting this issue really.

Comment: I've restarted Xcode and tried 7.2 but nope still not working. It's very frustrating.